# Convert object property with string index notation to dot notation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, query-string

I'm scratching my head a bit with this one. I have a URL as follows

```
http://localhost:50303/Directory?SearchUnits=km&Postcode=NG1%202AD&&Position[south]=53.9480673197085&Position[west]=-1.1444808302915135&Position[north]=52.9507652802915&Position[east]=-1.1417828697085497
```

When I get the query parameters using angularjs like so

```
var qs = $location.search();
```

I get an object like this

```
{ 
  SearchUnits: "km", 
  Postcode: "NG1 2AD", 
  "Position[south]": "53.9480673197085", 
  "Position[west]": "-1.1444808302915135", 
  "Position[north]": "52.9507652802915", 
  "Position[east]": "-1.1417828697085497" 
}
```

However I need it to look like this

```
{ 
  SearchUnits: "km", 
  Postcode: "NG1 2AD", 
  Position: { 
     south: "53.9480673197085", 
     west: "-1.1444808302915135", 
     north: "52.9507652802915", 
     east: "-1.1417828697085497"
  }
}
```

How do I go about parsing it? I have tried stringifying and then parsing but that doesn't work, any help would be appreciated

Comment: You can not do that using the url. Pass the data using post instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the key values are static, then it's pretty easy to transform it, just iterate over an array of `['south', 'west', 'north', 'east']` and retrieve values/assign/delete as needed:

```js
const obj = { 
  SearchUnits: "km", 
  Postcode: "NG1 2AD", 
  "Position[south]": "53.9480673197085", 
  "Position[west]": "-1.1444808302915135", 
  "Position[north]": "52.9507652802915", 
  "Position[east]": "-1.1417828697085497" 
};
const Position = {};
obj.Position = Position;
['south', 'west', 'north', 'east'].forEach((key) => {
  const inputKey = `Position[${key}]`;
  Position[key] = obj[inputKey];
  delete obj[inputKey];
});


console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was trying to avoid. Anyway, fields are static so it worked.